# Co-planar unit vectors and their resultants.

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $\bf a,b,c$ be three co-planar unit vectors such that $\bf a\hat \;b=\theta,b\hat\;c=2\theta$ where $\bf x\hat\;b$ is the angle between two vectors. Two vectors $\bf p,q$ are given by $$\bf p=a+a\times b+c\\ q=a-a\times b-c$$ where $\theta\in(0,\pi)$:

I need to find when the inequation $\bf p^2+q^2-2.5|p+q|>0$ is true and the range of $\bf\frac{|p-q|}{p^2+q^2}$.

---

I letted $\bf n=\widehat{a\times b}$ then $\bf p,q$ will be:
$$\bf p=a+n\sin\theta+c\\ q=a-n\sin\theta-c$$ 
So:
$$\bf p^2=2+2\cos3\theta+\sin^2\theta\\q^2=2-2\cos3\theta+\sin^2\theta\\
|p+q|=2,|p-q|=2\sqrt{(\sin^2\theta+1)}$$ after solving ahead my answers to inequation and range seems wrong because for $\theta=0$ range must include $1/2$ but answers have no $1/2$

Comment: What does $\bf{p}^2$ mean?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese $\bf{p^2}$$=|\vec p|^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|\vec p|=\sqrt{\vec a^2+(\vec a\times\vec b)^2+\vec c^2+2\vec a.(\vec a\times\vec b)+2\vec c.(\vec a\times\vec b)+2\vec a.\vec c}\\|\vec p|=\sqrt{2+\sin^2\theta+2\vec a.\vec c}$$
Similiarly:
$$|\vec q|=\sqrt{2+\sin^2\theta-2\vec a.\vec c}$$
Also $|\vec p+\vec q|=2$
Now $|\vec p|^2+|\vec q|^2-2.5|\vec p+\vec q|>0$
$$\implies 2+\sin^2\theta+2\vec a.\vec c+2+\sin^2\theta-2\vec a.\vec c-2.5(2)>0$$
$$2\sin^2\theta-1>0\implies \theta\in\left(\frac{\pi}4,\frac{3\pi}4\right)$$
Now let $$y=\frac{|\vec p-\vec q|}{|\vec p|^2+|\vec q|^2}=\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin^2\theta}}{2+\sin^2\theta}$$
$$\frac{dy}{d\theta}=\frac{-\sin^2\theta\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2\theta}(2+\sin^2\theta)^2}=0$$
$$\implies \theta=0,\pi,\frac{\pi}2\quad\text{Therefore the range is }\left[\frac{\sqrt2}3,\frac12\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

for me:

$$\bf p^2=2-2\cos3\theta+\sin^2\theta\\q^2=2+2\cos3\theta+\sin^2\theta\\$$
but it doesn't matter for their sum.
$$ p^2+q^2=2(2+\sin^2\theta)\\$$

$$|p+q|=2,|p-q|=2\sqrt{(\sin^2\theta+1)}$$
The inequation becomes: 
$$2(2+\sin^2\theta)-5>0$$
$$\sin^2\theta >\frac{1}{2}$$

so $$θ∈]\frac{π}{4},\frac{3π}{4}[$$

and the range of $$\frac{|p-q|}{p^2+q^2}=\frac{\sqrt{(\sin^2\theta+1)}}{2+\sin^2\theta}$$
so $$\theta ∈[\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3},\frac{1}{2}]$$

Cheers

Comment: I did mentiuon that range didnt include 0.5 for second part yet your answer does?